# Create cookie using ionic angularjs and persist the cookie to a long time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I do create a login system into Ionic/angularjs framework.

I would like to store a cookie and set the expires for a long time, so the user does not need to login every time as it is an internal app.

I just add http post to this controller, could not handle the cookie dependencies yet and the cookie creation:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http, $location, $state ) { //, $cookieStore, Auth
  $scope.loginData = {};
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    if(!angular.isDefined($scope.loginData.login)
        || !angular.isDefined($scope.loginData.password)
        || $scope.loginData.login.trim() == ""
        || $scope.loginData.password.trim() == ""){

       alert("Digite seu usuário e senha");
       return;
    }

    $http.post('http://www.somedomain.com/somefile.php',$scope.loginData)
      .then(
        function(result) {
          $scope.response = result;
          angular.forEach(result.data, function(value, key) {
            console.log(key + ': ' + value);
            if( value.slice(-1) == 1 ) {
              $location.path('/app/playlists');
            } else {
                $ionicModal.fromTemplate('<button class=button>try again</button>').show();
            }
          });
      });
  };
  $scope.logout = function() {
    Auth.logout();
    $state.go("acesso");
  };
})
```

Comment: You can use LocalStorage or SessionStorage, makes more sense than cookie for hybrid apps!

Comment: Can i set the expire date if use localStorage?

Comment: makes more sense your server set the expiration and invalidate the ticket instead of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular-local-storage` , you can work with `setStorageCookie`, here is the link to documentation : https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: Did not know this module will try to create the session or cookie and see if i can persist it for a long time.

Comment: Anyone already uses ngstorage? can i set the session expiring date using ngstorage?

Comment: I do use ngstorage module install using bower and set a variable using : `$scope.$storage = $localStorage;`
              `$scope.$storage.login = "authenticated";` can i set the expiring date  using ngstorage?

Comment: hey @ÂngeloRigo there is no harm in using ngStorage, but it does not work on some mobile devices, ngStorage variables returns null every time. angular-local-storage performance is very persistent.

Comment: I´m having the error message:  localStorageService is not defined. I do set the data :

`localStorageService.set('localStorageAuthenticated','authenticated');`

In app.js i do inject  ...

`angular.module('starter', ['ionic',                           
                            'LocalStorageModule'
                          ], function($httpProvider)
{
`
  ... And do a simple check by the  local data :

  `if( localStorageService.get('localStorageAuthenticated') == "authenticated" ){   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
  } ` what may i miss ?

Comment: can you please make a basic plnkr or fiddle, so i can see what is wrong.

Comment: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/inHsal3PxnrwlxJtLkAi?p=preview) here i have app.js and controller.js inside appCtrl i check if the data for login has already been set before. Inthe browser if i do login navigate and try to login again is still falling into the login template

Comment: As your plkn is not in working state, check this [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CvvVPcCJufmGYi6X5fH?p=preview) , i have made a very basic integration of localstorage.